# Four concyclic triangle centers

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, elementary-proofs, triangles

Can you prove the claim given below? Inspired by [Lester's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lester%27s_theorem) I have formulated the following claim:

> **Claim.** Given any scalene triangle $\triangle ABC$ . Let $D$ be the reflection of incenter in sideline $AB$, and define $E$ and $F$ cyclically. The lines $CD$, $BF$, $AE$ concur in [X(79)](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html) . Then, the two Fermat points , incenter and $X(79)$ lie on the same circle.

[image]

GeoGebra applet that demonstrates this claim can be found [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/r63eeexm).

Comment: Please see here: I found 6 year ago http://geometry-math-journal.ro/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/5.pdf

Comment: @ĐàoThanhOai Thank you for the link.

Answer (score -2):

There is a standard method to solve this problem (using the $p,q$ method) which can be used to attack the general one  of when four given triangle centres are cyclic for any triangle.  We suppose that the centres have functions $f_1,\dots,f_4$ where we can assume wlog that each $f$ is homogeneous and has cyclic sum $1$ (we are using the concepts and terminology of the Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers).
Then we can regard the determinant of the $4$ by $4$ matrix with rows $$x_i^2+y_i^2\quad x_i\quad y_i\quad 1,$$ as a function of $p,q$ where
$$(x_i,y_i)=(f_i(b,1,a)+pf_i(1,a,b),\ qf_i(1,a,b)),$$
$a^2=(p-1)^2+q^2$ and $b^2=p^2+q^2$.  The required condition is that this be the zero function. For simple centre functions it can be computed by hand and it is easy to write a programme, say in Mathematica, to attack the general case.